# error while trying to resize the partition

Tags: disk, gparted, disk-utility

im running out of space and i tried to resize the partition using g-parted but i got an error:

```
Checking for bad sectors ...
Bad cluster: 0x2904636 - 0x2904636 (1)
Bad cluster: 0x290526d - 0x290526e (2)
Bad cluster: 0x29052fd - 0x2905300 (4)
Bad cluster: 0x2905392 - 0x2905392 (1)
Bad cluster: 0x2905425 - 0x2905428 (4)
Bad cluster: 0x290555d - 0x2905560 (4)
Bad cluster: 0x29055f1 - 0x29055f8 (8)
Bad cluster: 0x2905681 - 0x2905688 (8)
Bad cluster: 0x29057ac - 0x29057ac (1)
Bad cluster: 0x29887dd - 0x29887dd (1)
Bad cluster: 0x299a086 - 0x299a086 (1)
Bad cluster: 0x348ec05 - 0x348ec05 (1)
Bad cluster: 0x353dabb - 0x353dabb (1)
Bad cluster: 0x353dba4 - 0x353dba4 (1)
Bad cluster: 0x354a162 - 0x354a162 (1)
Bad cluster: 0x354a1ce - 0x354a1ce (1)
ERROR: This software has detected that the disk has at least 40 bad sectors.
****************************************************************************
* WARNING: The disk has bad sector. This means physical damage on the disk *
* surface caused by deterioration, manufacturing faults or other reason. *
* The reliability of the disk may stay stable or degrade fast. We suggest *
* making a full backup urgently by running 'ntfsclone --rescue ...' then *
* run 'chkdsk /f /r' on Windows and rebooot it TWICE! Then you can resize *
* NTFS safely by additionally using the --bad-sectors option of ntfsresize.*
****************************************************************************
```

I opened the "disk utility" and clicked on "Smart DATA" button I got this image:

[image: Smart data on disk utility]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### STOP!

Backup everything important. See [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

This is a:

## Potential Hard Drive failure.

Comment: is there any way i can fix this without buying a new hard drive.

Comment: get a new disk and recover as much as possible https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got a bad hard drive. Might be time for a new one

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i guess im just gonna buy a new one.